# How does iOS app remembers my permission, even though I deleted it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, permission, privacy

I noticed that at least one iOS app, remembered that I earlier gave it permission to send me notification and access my location, even though I have deleted it, and then re-installed it.

What am I supposed to do in order to full delete an App with all related data? I'm using iOS 13.

Comment: Did you talk to the developer of that app?  Many apps store user data in their own (or cloud) servers/databases.  Deleting the app from your device doesn't include removing the account info from the developer's site.

Comment: I want to prevent the app from cyber-stalking me in case I create a totally new user account. therefore, the fact they keep my previous user data is not my main concern. my concern is data that identifies my individual device. Also, privacy setting like location sure have nothing to do with with a cloud of a third party, but rather with my device.

Comment: Many times there's been requests here where people try to bypass app restrictions by creating new accounts.  Most developers know how to prevent that by unique identifiers on your device.  Then, they store that info in their database (in the cloud).

Comment: but what are those unique identifiers? if they are stored on their cloud, they need to cross-check them with the info on my device. so what info on my device is accessible to them, and how may I modify it, when it comes to iOS?

Comment: @thenondeveloper App developers can save unique identifiers to the Keychain on the device. This data is not removed when you delete the app - if you later reinstall the app, that app will have access to the unique identifier. This can be used by app developers to ensure that users are not cheating the system (by for example claiming single-use free offers multiple times, or similar). The only way to delete said Keychain data is to ensure that you do not sync the keychain contents to the iCloud, and that you remove everything from the phone (i.e. use 'Erase all contents and Settings').

Answer (score 2):

App permissions are stored somehow by the system, not the app itself. In order to use location, microphone etc. app has to "ask" the system if it can use it. So I suspect there's some kind of system database where permissions are saved (I can't find the exact mechanism).

Answer (score -1):

It's Icloud , Icloud cached installed app permission data.
Turn off the Icloud Sync and then reinstall app.